# getContentHeight in @monaco-editor/react does not look correct

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I'm trying to use https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react. But I realize that its `getContentHeight` does not match the behavior described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/794#issuecomment-688959283).

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-en8wpm?file=EditorBasic.tsx,App.tsx,index.html. It starts with `500px`, once we enter a newline, it becomes `518px`, then another newline leads to `536px`, etc. From what I understand, `getContentHeight` should not include the height of the editor.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MonacoEditor from '@monaco-editor/react';

export default class EditorBasic extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  editor: any;

  _handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    this.editor = editor;
    this.editor.onDidContentSizeChange(this.handleResize.bind(this));
  }

  updateHeight = () => {
    console.log(
      'this.editor.getContentHeight()',
      this.editor.getContentHeight()
    );
  };

  handleResize() {
    if (this.editor && this.editor !== undefined) {
      this.updateHeight();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MonacoEditor
        width="400px"
        height="500px"
        options={{ minimap: { enabled: false }, lineNumbers: 'off' }}
        defaultLanguage="javascript"
        defaultValue="content"
        onMount={this._handleEditorDidMount.bind(this)}
        theme="vs-dark"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know if it's a bug of @monaco-editor/react? Is there any other API to get the real content height?

(* Link in GitHub: https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react/issues/442 *)

Comment: I'm seeing similar problems with the Monaco editor and Svelte, so I suspect the problem is Monaco.